# Plupload amazon S3 Cache-Control

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3, cache-control, plupload

we are uploading images using PLupload to amazon S3 bucket. 
But we need to set cache-control for the uploaded file.

I have tried adding headers {'cache-control':'155520000'}, and also adding it under the multipart_params. no luck.

the following is the code we use.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function() {
    $('#progressbar').hide();
    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        init : {
            FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
                plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                    if (up.files.length > 1) {
                        up.removeFile(file);
                    }
                });
            },
        },
        preinit : {

            UploadFile: function(up, file) {
                var filenamevous;
                if('thumb' in file){
                    up.settings.multipart_params.key = 'thumb_'+imagename;  
                }
                else
                {
                    up.settings.multipart_params.key = makeid()+'.jpg';  
                }

                imagename = up.settings.multipart_params.key;
                var filenamevous;
                filenamevous = $("#txtImageTitle").val();

                var category;
                category = $("#category").val();
                $.post("<?php echo $this->config->item('actionFeUrl'); ?>/pictures/ajax",{imname:imagename,oriname:filenamevous,catName:category,task:'uploadedimage'},function(data)
                {

                });
            }
        },

        runtimes : 'flash,silverlight,html5',
        browse_button : 'pickfiles',
        container : 'container',
        max_file_size : '10mb',
        multi_selection: false,
        multipart: true,
        multipart_params: {
            'key': '${filename}',
            'Filename': '${filename}',
            'acl': 'public-read',
            'success_action_status': '201',
            'AWSAccessKeyId' : '<?php echo $accessKeyId; ?>',  
            'policy': '<?php echo $policy; ?>',
            'signature': '<?php echo $signature; ?>'
        },
        url : 'http://<?php echo $bucket; ?>.s3.amazonaws.com/',
        flash_swf_url : '<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',
        silverlight_xap_url : '<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap',
        filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
        {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
        ],
    });


    $('#uploadfiles').click(function(e) {


        var pattern = '<?php echo $blackListedWordsPattern; ?>';
        var patt=new RegExp(pattern,"gi");
        var value = $('#txtImageTitle').val();
        if(value==""){
            showAlertPopUp('Please enter title.');
            return false;
        }
        if(patt.test(value)) //value is the value from the input feild
        {
            showAlertPopUp('Name contains a black listed words.');
            return false;
        }

        if($("#category").val()==""){
            showAlertPopUp('Please select category.');
            return false;
        }
        $('#uploadfiles').hide();
        $('#progressbar').show();

        uploader.start();
        e.preventDefault();

    });
    uploader.init();
    uploader.splice();
    uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function(up, file) {
        if('thumb' in file){
            up.settings.resize = {width : 190, height : 143, quality : 100};
        }
        else{
            up.settings.resize = {width : 700, height : 450, quality : 100};
        }
    });

    uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
        $.each(files, function(i, file) {
            $('#filelist').html(
            '<div style="float:right" id="' + file.id + '">' +
            file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b>' +
            '</div>');
        });

        up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
    });

    uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file) {
        $('#' + file.id + " b").html("100%");
        if(!('thumb' in file)) {

            file.thumb = true;
            file.loaded = 0;
            file.percent = 0;
            file.status = plupload.QUEUED;
            up.trigger("QueueChanged");
            up.refresh();

        }
    });



    uploader.bind('Error', function(up, err) {
        $('#filelist').append("<div>Error: " + err.code +
        ", Message: " + err.message +
        (err.file ? ", File: " + err.file.name : "") +
        "</div>"
        );

        up.refresh(); // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

multipart_params used to send/post the data along with your upload request,

for changing headers you may add a property - header,

hope this would help :

http://www.plupload.com/docs/Options#headers